# Capture multiples groups in regex

Tags: java, css, regex

I want to parse some CSS in Java.

It doesn't have to be perfect and should only capture a specific style class.

Let's assume the CSS looks something like this:

```
.someunimportantclass .txt-value .input-suffix {
    margin-left: 4px;
}

/* Table Columns */

body.thisone table .column-bic {
    min-width: 70px;
}

body.thisone table .column-char35,
body.thisone table .column-somethingdifferent,
body.thisone table .column-somethingdifferent2,
body.thisone table .column-closebutstilldifferent {
{
    min-width: 245px;
}

body.thisone table .column-code {
    min-width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My approach with regex works only partial. Right now I have:

```regex
body.thisone table \.([a-z]*-[\w]*) \{[\s]*(.*)\: ([\w]*);
```

Which captures all the single-line-classes. It doesn't work with multiple classes with the same attribute(s) or with classes with several attributes. I experimented a little bit with the group-"flags" (like + and ?) but couldn't really figure out how to do.

Another problem I haven't really thought about is how to map those groups into Java Objects. With just one attribute to one class it is as easy as

```
for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i += 3) {
    classes.add(matcher.group(i));
    attributes.put(matcher.group(i + 1), matcher.group(i + 2));
}
```

with classes as `List<String>` and attributes as `Map<String, String>`.

But off the top of my mind I cannot come up with a way to do it with several classes and / or attributes.

Comment: I was about to post an answer, but I don't understand what you mean with mapping groups to objects?

Comment: I am sorry, not Objects, just as Strings into the Map.

Comment: Okay, with you so far, one more question, will you do this with Java 8 or Java 7-?

Comment: Java EE 6, so Java 7-

Comment: Why did you remove your answer? I couldn't look into it over the weekend and only scanned it. Now I have the time to do so and I cannot access the answer...

Comment: Eh, I was going to revise it, but got sidetracked. I'll undelete it, bare in mind it's a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your efforts! It can at least give me enough help to maybe sove it myself. If you feel the answer is good enough I will accept is as the answer.

Comment: Feel free to do so. I may add a new section under the current solution shortly with a better solution, but if it works for you you can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
    String foo = ".someunimportantclass .txt-value .input-suffix {\n" + 
        "    margin-left: 4px;\n" + 
        "}\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "/* Table Columns */\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-bic {\n" + 
        "    min-width: 70px;\n" + 
        "}\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-char35,\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-somethingdifferent,\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-somethingdifferent2,\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-closebutstilldifferent {\n" + 
        "{\n" + 
        "    min-width: 245px;\n" + 
        "}\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "body.thisone table .column-code {\n" + 
        "    min-width: 25px;\n" + 
        "    text-align: center;\n" + 
        "}";
    String key = "body.thisone table";
```

If what I expected of the data structure to be correct, they will be similar to:

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> matchingClasses = new HashMap<>();
```

The pattern to find a CSS Class name with similar structure would be:

```
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key + "\\s\\.([a-z]*-[\\w]*)(?:,[^{]+)?\\s*");
```

And then we can capture its contents with a lookahead, so that colliding classes can be re-matched as well:

```
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key + "\\s\\.([a-z]*-[\\w]*)(?=(?:,[^{]+)?\\s*" +
    //                                       "{\\s*(.*?)\\s*)");
```

Since the CSS class contents are multi-line we have to compile this with `DOTALL`.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key + "\\s\\.([a-z]*-[\\w]*)(?=(?:,[^{]+)?\\s*" +
                                          "{\\s*(.*?)\\s*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

From there we can match with the regex, after compiling another pattern to break down the CSS class contents:

```
    Pattern content = Pattern.compile("([\\w-]+)\\s*:\\s*([^;]+);");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(foo);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // matcher.group(1); // This is the class name.
        // matcher.group(2); // This is the class contents.
```

We can get the attribute value pairs like this:

```
        HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        Matcher contents = content.matcher(matcher.group(2));
        while (contents.find())
            attributes.put(contents.group(1), contents.group(2));
```

And then add it into our `matchingClasses` hashmap.

```
        if (! attributes.isEmpty())
            matchingClasses.put(matcher.group(1), attributes);
    }
```

Comment: Today I had the time to look into it and implement it as a prototype. There were some minor issues (escape the { and } in pattern).
If run the matcher has zero findings and therefore returns null.
I would love to debug the RegEx myself but I can't get around the lookahead which is a rather confusing concept to me...
I am sorry to bother you again but is it possible to look into it?